# Drop on fullcalendar not working after adding script with events laravel

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Hi there I have this problem with the calendar when I try to drag and drop, it drags the event but then it does not drop on the calendar,

```js
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js'></script> 
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            // put your options and callbacks here
            events : [
                @foreach($appointments as $appointment)
                {
                    title : '{{ $appointment->firstname }}',
                    start : '{{ $appointment->start_at }}',
                   
                },
                @endforeach
            ],
   

        })

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 
      editable: true,
      droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
      drop: function() {
        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
          // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
          $(this).remove();
        }
      }
    });
    });
</script>
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('app/assets/libs/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css') }}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('app/assets/extra-libs/calendar/calendar.css') }}"/>
  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Agents</h4>
                               
                                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                   
                                    @foreach($agents as $key=> $agent)
                                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link @if($key == 0)active @endif" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{$agent->id}}" role="tab" style="text-align: center;">
                                        <div class="user-profile dropdown m-t-20">
                                     <div class="user-pic">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('app/assets/images/users/1.jpg') }}" alt="users" class="rounded-circle img-fluid" />
                                </div></div><span class="hidden-xs-down">{{$agent->name}}</span></a> 
                                 </li>
                                 @endforeach
                           
                              
                                </ul>

            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content tabcontent-border">
               
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="{{$agent->id}}" role="tabpanel">

                    
                    <div class="p-20">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3 border-right p-r-0">
                                        <div class="card-body border-bottom">
                                            <h4 class="card-title m-t-10">Drag & Drop Event</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                    <div id="calendar-events" class="">
                                                        @foreach($appointments as $appointment)
                                                        <div class="calendar-events m-b-20 draggable" data-class="bg-info"><i class="fa fa-circle text-info m-r-10"></i>
                                                            {{$appointment->firstname }} <br>   {{$appointment->start_at}}</div>

 
                                                      
                                                            @endforeach

                                                       <!--  <div class="calendar-events m-b-20" data-class="bg-success"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success m-r-10"></i> Event Two</div>
                                                        <div class="calendar-events m-b-20" data-class="bg-danger"><i class="fa fa-circle text-danger m-r-10"></i>Event Three</div>
                                                        <div class="calendar-events m-b-20" data-class="bg-warning"><i class="fa fa-circle text-warning m-r-10"></i>Event Four</div> -->
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!-- checkbox -->
                                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="drop-remove">
                                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="drop-remove">Remove after drop</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-new-event" class="btn m-t-20 btn-info btn-block waves-effect waves-light">
                                                            <i class="ti-plus"></i> Add New Event
                                                        </a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                                        <div class="card-body b-l calender-sidebar">
                                            <div id="calendar"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             
                
            </div>
            
           <!--  <div class="tab-pane  p-20" id="profile" role="tabpanel">2</div>
            <div class="tab-pane p-20" id="messages" role="tabpanel">3</div> -->
         </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The appointment are shown on my calendar  I want to be able to drag an event and drop to the calendar the drag and drop was working, but when I added the script with the events that show the appointments inside the calendar the drop does not work and on console does not show any error. Can someone help me ?

Comment: fullcalendar required jQuery 2.0 or above, but you're using 1.11. So first please update that to a supported version and then see if your issue still persists.

Comment: Also in your demo above you've shown us server-side code rather than the finished JavaScript and HTML. So from that it's difficult for us to actually reproduce your problem because the finished state of the page is uncertain. It would be better if you used the View Source tool in your browser to get the finished document which is sent to the browser, and paste that into your question instead.